# error while creating bean org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When I try to create the bean for org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager, I get org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

I'm using:

- Hibernate 4.0.1.Final
- Spring 3.2.2.RELEASE
- Spring Tool Suite, Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE, Build Id: 201503100339, Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)
- JDK 1.7
- Tomcat v8.0 Server

This is the daos.xml file where I configure Hibernate daos and sessionFactory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">


    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="load*" read-only="true" rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="reload*" read-only="true" rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>


    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="transactionalMethods"
            expression="execution(* com.walook.saico.servicios..*ServiceImpl.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="transactionalMethods" />
    </aop:config>

    <bean id="abstractDao" abstract="true"
        class="com.myapp.persistence.daos.AbstractHibernateDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="comunMappings" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <value>/com/myapp/persistence/mappings/User.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <!-- <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/> -->
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true='T',false='F'</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <constructor-arg>
            <array>
                <ref bean="comunMappings" />
            </array>
        </constructor-arg>

    </bean>

    <bean id="usuarioDao" class="com.myapp.persistence.daos.UserDaoImpl"
        parent="abstractDao"></bean>
</beans>
```

This is my pom.xml configuration for maven dependency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>My App</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>oops.util.lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapdb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapdb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.fastinfoset</groupId>
            <artifactId>FastInfoset</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>${ehcache.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jpwgen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jpwgen</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.javacsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>javacsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring.ws.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
        <spring.test.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.test.version>
        <poi.version>3.9</poi.version>
        <c3p0.version>0.9.1.2</c3p0.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.0.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <ehcache.version>2.7.0</ehcache.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>srvAppDev2</id>
            <name>srvAppDev2-releases</name>
            <url>http://localhost/:8081/artifactory/ext-release-local</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

This is the error log trace I get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'txManager' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/config/daos.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedCollection(TypeConverterDelegate.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:93)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:686)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedArray(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:150)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:629)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1051)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory.<clinit>(CollectionFactory.java:76)
    ... 54 more
```

What is wrong with my xml configuration file?

Comment: Check your dependencies, make sure you aren't mixing versions. Another note don't mess around with the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` as that will break proper tx integration and the `hibernate.connection` property is useless as you are injecting a datasource.

Comment: I've edited my question adding the pom.xml configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just changed my sts for:

- Spring Tool Suite
- Version: 3.6.4.RELEASE
- Build Id: 201503100339
- Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.2)

and it worked.

I also changed daos.xml configuration as follows just to avoid writeing each hbm configuration file route by adding mappingDirectoryLocations property to sessionFactory (myapp worked just by changeing my sts veresion, this daos.xml configuration was just to optimize the old one):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernateProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location"
            value="${hibernate.properties.location}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice"  transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="load*" read-only="true" rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="reload*" read-only="true" rollback-for="Throwable" />
            <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Throwable" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>


    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="transactionalMethods" expression="execution(* com.myapp.services..*ServiceImpl.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="transactionalMethods" />
    </aop:config>

    <bean id="abstractDao" abstract="true"
        class="com.myapp.persistence.daos.AbstractHibernateDao">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProperties"/>
        <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations" value="${hibernate.mappings.location}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="usuarioDao" class="com.myapp.persistence.daos.UserDaoImpl"
            parent="abstractDao"></bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `LocalSessionFactoryBean` has no constructor arguments (See [JavaDoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#LocalSessionFactoryBean--))
2. You can use `public void setMappingLocations(Resource... mappingLocations)` (see JavaDocs to)
3. You can follow Mkyong [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-xml-example/), it's well explained

Also this is way I configure my session factory:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

        <property name="dataSource">
            <ref bean="dataSource" />
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>

        <property name="mappingLocations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:com/fenix/infrastructure/persistence/db/mapping/Usuario.hbm.xml
                </value>
                <value>classpath:com/fenix/infrastructure/persistence/db/mapping/ConfirmacionCorreo.hbm.xml
                </value>
                ...
            </list>
        </property>

    </bean>
```

Comment: Now sessionFactory bean can not be initialized, I also downloaded Mkyong example and I have the same error, sessionFactory can not be initialized.

Could it be sts version?

Answer (score 1):

First I would check your class path to see if you don't have mixed dependencies for spring related jars.

Then I would remove the `java.util.ArrayList` bean and either use the `<util:list />` or just inline it inside the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` configuration. The latter situation is the most common way to define your mapping files. Next to that the `LocalSessionFactoryBean` doesn't take a constructor argument so that bean definition is already wrong.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.substitutions">true='T',false='F'</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/com/myapp/persistence/mappings/User.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I also removed the `hibernate.connection.*` properties as those aren't doing anything due to the injection of a `DataSource`. Also the `hibernate.current_session_context_class` is removed as that is set by Spring already. Messing around with that usually breaks proper transaction management.